# Best Practice to use IIS and asp.net core web application On Docker Container?

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis

I set up my ASP.Net Core 3.1 web application on a Docker image that now I can run the image and start its container and access to my WebApplication via kestrel(its stand-alone webserver) in my localhost.

Now it's my question: what is the best practice to use application container and IIS in a real production environment to handle public requests from the web?

for example:

Use IIS in a separated container and connect it to my WebApp container?

Or Put IIS and my WebApp in a single container?

Or Use IIS on my server (which contains WebApp Container) and connect it to my web app Container?

Or something else?

Comment: When you host a web app in a container environment, such as Kubernetes, there is a standardized approach to expose the web app to the outside, https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-appand IIS no longer matters.

Comment: I suggest you use IIS on the server and connect it to your web app container, usually we do this, and it is not easy to cause problems.

Comment: @LexLi thanks, but your link won't work for me! Do you say that  Kubernetes is used as a reverse proxy like IIS or Nginx in this ecosystem?

Comment: @Mohammad have you find any answer? mamnoon misham befarmayead.

Comment: @GuidoMocha I post my answer to my question for you friend.

Answer (score 0):

My question came from the Microservice concept in the production environment. Although Kestrel is used as a fast webserver there are a lot of things that **IIS** has them but **kestrel** doesn't have!

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/when-to-use-a-reverse-proxy?view=aspnetcore-5.0) you can see more info about "When to use Kestrel with a reverse proxy".

In microservice, it's important to use API Gateway(like Ocelot or Envoy) to reroute HTTP requests, in other words, API Gateways are front-ends or façades surfacing only the services. We still need some mature web servers like IIS or using [Kubernetes Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)(based on Nginx) in front of the API gateways. (for more info see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot#using-kubernetes-ingress-plus-ocelot-api-gateways))

I found that we can use Kubernetes Ingress or IIS to a middle-tier between API gateway and Internet to have more options. So we can use IIS in our docked container to handle it (Read [Here](https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2020/06/23/deploying-an-aspnet-core-web-applications-to-docker/))